# How to Stop hibernate from recursively loading the entities

Tags: performance, hibernate, query-optimization

I have the following setting in Db represented here in sample hib classes

> Class A{
>   private B b;
>   }
>
> Class B{
>    private C c; 
>   }
>
> class C{
>   private D d; 
>   }

Sample HQL:  from A a left join a.b ;

This recursively loads all the entities from A to D. How to selectively load entities say in this case i would want it to load till B ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mapping-files you could tell hibernate to lazy-load the entities.
This way the entity won't be loaded unless you access the property.
Below is an example of how you setup lazy-loading of the entities.
The class A and B is always loaded, but the rest is loaded only after you try and access their properties.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="TestNamespace.A, TestNamespace" table="A" lazy="false" />
  <many-to-one name="B" column="B" />
</hibernate-mapping>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="TestNamespace.B, TestNamespace" table="B" lazy="false" />
  <many-to-one name="C" column="C" />
</hibernate-mapping>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="TestNamespace.C, TestNamespace" table="C" lazy="true" />
  <many-to-one name="D" column="D" />
</hibernate-mapping>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="TestNamespace.D, TestNamespace" table="D" lazy="true" />
  <property name="SomeProperty" column="SomeColumn" />
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Best of luck

Comment: Is there a way to lazy load one-one entities ?

Comment: As far as I know this isn't supported by Hibernate, I saw a post about something similar that had a workaround for it. See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965059/how-to-lazy-load-a-one-to-one-composition-via-hql